# How to exclude a JSON property from comparison

Tags: c#, json.net, fluent-assertions

How to exclude a JSON property from comparison in `FluentAssertions.Json`?

```cs
JToken token, expectedJson;
token.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedJson);
```

```json
{
  "property1":"value1",
  "property2":"value2",
  "property3":"value3"
}
```

I want to exclude property with name "property2" from the comparison. How is it possible?

Comment: Did you read the [readme](https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions.json)? You should probably configure some `IJsonAssertionOptions<>`

Comment: You mean something like `token.Should().BeEquivilentTo(expectedJson, o=>o.Excluding(p=>p.Property2));`

Comment: There is no Excluding method in IJsonAssertionOptions interface.

Comment: @AndrejB. Do you have Exclude ? 
something like token.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedJson, options =>
    options.For(o => o.Property1).Exclude(o => o.Property2));

Comment: I found that I have a restriction by using net462. FluentAssertions for net462 does not have overload of BeEquivilentTo with the options. So, I fixed it with another approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by preprocessing of token and expectedJson.

```
JToken token, expectedJson;
((JValue)expectedJson.SelectToken("property2")).Value = null;
((JValue)token.SelectToken("property2")).Value = null;
token.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedJson);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could test the properties directly and not the whole object.

Comment: This is a poor answer.   Checking properties individually is not very good future proofing.